# Update statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am writing an Update trigger and am struggling with the Update statement:

The statement is as below:

```
UPDATE ARGUS_APP.CMN_REG_REPORTS CARR 
SET CARR.DATE_SUBMITTED =
(
  SELECT To_Date(M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGEDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') Messagedate 
  FROM esm_owner.MESSAGES M 
  WHERE M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA' 
)
WHERE  CARR.DATE_SUBMITTED =
(
  SELECT CARR.DATE_SUBMITTED  
  FROM  esm_owner.safetyreport sr,esm_owner.MESSAGES M,ARGUS_APP.CMN_REG_REPORTS CARR 
  WHERE sr.report_id=CARR.esm_report_id 
    AND M.msg_id  = sr.msg_id 
    AND M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA' 
)
```

I get ORA:01427 everytime.

The Table structure is as below:

I have 3 tables

1. ARGUS_APP.CMN_REG_REPORTS CARR .............having the columns DATE_SUBMITTED(which I want to update) and esm_report_id which joins with the report_id of safety report
2. ESM_OWNER.SAFETYREPORT SR............having the columns report_id and MSG_ID(joined with the msg_id of the MESSAGES table)
3. MESSAGES M ..........having the columns MSG_ID and ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: One of your sub queries is returning more than one row which is what is causing the error. It's not clear from your question how you'd like to resolve this.

Comment: Either `Messages` is not unique on `MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER` or you've got something wrong with your other sub-query... I don't see how we can help without more information and we certainly can't help quicker than you can work it out for yourself....

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild stab and guess that this is what you are after. They key feature is correlating the subselects with the update (the `carr` in the subselects refer to the table in the outer statement).

```
Update
    argus_app.cmn_reg_reports carr
set 
    carr.date_submitted = (
        Select
            To_Date(m.AcknowledgmentHeader.MessageDate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') Messagedate 
        from 
            esm_owner.Messages m
                inner join
            esm_owner.SafetyReport sr
                on m.msg_id = sr.msg_id
        where
            carr.esm_report_id = sr.report_id And
            m.AcknowledgmentHeader.MessageSenderIdentifier = 'PMDA'
        )
Where
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            esm_owner.Messages m
                Inner Join
            esm_owner.SafetyReport sr
                on m.msg_id = sr.msg_id
        Where
            carr.esm_report_id = sr.report_id and
            m.AcknowledgmentHeader.MessageSenderIdentifier = 'PMDA' 
    )
```

Here's an example showing the basic principle works:

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e373e/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Both of the sub queries return 9 rows as I expect them to as I have used the filter condition 'PMDA' so I expect the update to map one to one and update the DATE values.

Comment: @ lAURENCE I did set up a test case ..How can I share that with you ?

Comment: I did omit the PMDA thing during creation

Comment: How can I see that on the URL ??

Comment: Is it the View Sample Fiddle button on the top ? But I cant see anything there

Comment: Hi Laurence, Further to the update statement I have modified my trigger which looks like this :

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ESM_OWNER.TRG_ACK_MESS
AFTER INSERT ON ESM_OWNER.MESSAGES 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
declare
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
Begin

Comment: Update
    argus_app.cmn_reg_reports carr
set 
    carr.date_submitted = (
        Select
            To_Date(m.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGEDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
        from 
            esm_owner.Messages m
                inner join
            esm_owner.SafetyReport sr
                on m.msg_id = sr.msg_id
        where
            carr.esm_report_id = sr.report_id And
            m.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA'
        )

Comment: Where
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            esm_owner.Messages m
                Inner Join
            esm_owner.SafetyReport sr
                on m.msg_id = sr.msg_id
        Where
            carr.esm_report_id = sr.report_id and
            m.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA'
    );
commit; 
END;
/

Comment: @user2106410 I think you would be better off asking a new question than trying to put this in comments.

Comment: I shall Ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your subqueries is probably returning more than one row of data. You could perhaps check this by running each on its own.

If you want the update to apply to them all, change the

```
... = (SELECT...
```

to

```
... IN (SELECT ...
```